# CPU frequency gets throttled when using multi-window on Kubuntu 18.10

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, 18.10, plasma, cpufreq

This is the current CPU frequency with power plugged in:

```
$ cpufreq-info | grep -i "current CPU freq"
  current CPU frequency is 1.54 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.58 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.73 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.83 GHz.
```

I tried uninstalling TLP, and it doesn't work.  Unplugging sometimes brings back the performance, but other times, it doesn't and requires a reboot (like right now).

After reboot (with only 1 monitor):

```
$ cpufreq-info | grep -i "current CPU freq"
  current CPU frequency is 2.95 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 2.79 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 2.85 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 2.78 GHz.
```

I'm just wondering if this is happening to anyone else?

This is my system info (copied from KInfoCenter):

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 18.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.2
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.54.0
Qt Version: 5.11.1
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-15-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?  The only one I tried out is uninstalling TLP, which (as mentioned before) didn't work.